# insert all for sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have 1 table in 2 diferent databases

> Database 1 
>   row1 I
>   row2 will
>   row3 fly
>   row4 high

> Database2 
>   row1 you
>   row2 will
>   row3 help
>   row4 me

what I want in the database2 is to overwrite all the columns data and replace by what database1 hold.

Desire results FOR DATABSE 2:

> row1 I
>   row2 will
>   row3 fly
>   row4 high

In my real problem i have more then 30 columns, I am searching for something similar to *insert all*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
delete from db2.tab
go
insert into db2.tab
select * from db1.tab
```